# OData Api controllers flattern request

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

This question deals with the different **"size"** of a returned JSON result from these two difference controllers (API vs OData). 
Some entities for example: (this is a **bad** composition and it was only made for making a point, please don't judge to relation between these entities)

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> CustomersInCategory { get; set; }
}
```

When making a GET request to an **OData** controller, say:

```
GET http://localhost:81/Customers
```

The result will **not** contain the Customers' Category object, unless I explicitly mention "$expand=Category" on the URL.

However,
The same request for an **API** controller, **will** return the Customers' Category object (even if the result is IQueryable<Customer>).
The **problem** with this is that in case of cyclic relations between entities, the result is recursively flatten in becomes enormous (might be infinity).

I've been looking for a solution for this problem all over and found stuff like MaxDepth that doesn't work and many other things that resulted nothing.

What I really want is a way to "tell" the API controller or its methods, to "DO not expand the result" - or better yet, ignore cyclic referencing (which I've also tried and didn't work).

**UPDATED**:
Here is the GET method on the API controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public IQueryable<Customer> Get()
{
     return _unitOfWork.Repository<Customer>().Query().Get();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In Web API case, are you using Lazy Loading? It sounds like it's Eager Loading?

Comment: Can you post your action definition in the controller, which is used to get customers?